# Boost converter design. Current issue

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, boost

Currently trying to make a boost converter working at a frequency of 100kHz.
For the design, I used the equations shown in https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva372c/slva372c.pdf , my requirements for the converter were Vin = 12V, Vout = 44V and I set Iout at 16A. For the design, I considered an efficiency of 100% (to determine duty cycle) knowing, of course, that this isn't happening in real life. With the equations shown I found that the inductance required was 4.96uH, although the minimum to prevent the inductor from reaching currents below zero was 0.665uH (to find this value, I set the current ripple in the inductor at 2*IL). I ended up lowering the inductance to 3.3uH once I had finished the simulation because I found some inductors with really good performance at 3.3uH and the circuit still operates properly.

I also found that the minimum capacitance was 80uF, but decided to use 100uF in order to decrease output voltage ripple.

[image]

(Right side of the circuit was just made to have a feedback of the output voltage and adjust the duty cycle automatically).

[image]

As can be seen in this picture, the DC-DC converter actually works (In this simulation I have also placed real diode and transistor, and also an ESR of the inductor to poorly simulate the loses).

This is the design so far, and I simulated this with good results. When it came to selecting components to make this circuit, I found that the capacitor ripple was really high (I didn't calculate the ripple, I got it from the simulation in Microcap) and I can't really find a proper capacitor.

[image]

This is the current through the capacitor, going from negative values when the MOSFET works as a short-circuit, since the capacitor is discharging, to high values of the current when the MOSFET is an open-circuit.

This question initially was posted asking which capacitor could make it work(in fact I reuploaded it since the original couldn't accepts answers anymore :s), but now I'm actually thinking that I may have done something wrong along the way. Is it normal to have such a huge ripple current for a boost converter that boosts from 12 to 44V (I don't seem to find the right capacitor for me)? I see you nowadays you can buy boost converters with really good performance and an extremely high efficiency, I understand I'm doing a way more low-key version of it, but I'm still confused about the results I'm getting. Actually, the only thing that makes me doubt about what I have done is the current at the capacitor, since is the only component that I can't find.

Comment: Sorry Kartman, I uploaded a new question trying to be more clear about my issue. Thanks for your comments on the last one x)

Comment: What's the ESR of that capacitor? Your control loop is fine and you get a stable output voltage, right? Would be interesting to see, how the converter performs depending on the load. In this case, the load will draw about 17A

Comment: Unfortunately the ESR is zero right now because I have been looking for a real capacitor that can handle that current ripple in order to set the ESR, but I have tried many ESR from 55mOmhs to 200mOhms and the performance is still fine(the issue I have is that I can't find the proper capacitor and don't really know if there is a kind that can handle high ripple currents). Answering to your second question, yes, is sets a stable output voltage and I made a study on how the load would affect but me and my team decided to set an output current of 16A since we want to use the converter for an UA.

Comment: Boost converters of this simple topology are always going to be significantly hampered when the power output requirement (770 watts) is this high. The inductor choice is going to be even more problematic than the capacitor choice also.

Comment: @mrssg You'd probably want to parallel multiple capacitors for something with this much power. Probably a couple small ceramic capacitors and a couple large electrolytic capacitors. Unrelated to the capacitor, I'm not sure about your choice of transistor; that gate charge is pretty high. Driving it might be difficult; you'd need a really good gate driver. And remember the current in your inductor and transistor are going to be significantly higher than the output current, and that you *absolutely cannot* allow the inductor to saturate.

Comment: A group of aluminum polymer capacitors in parallel can help you there. They can carry roughly 10 times the ripple current of standard electrolytic versions